# I have a byte[] and I want to convert it to a file without saving it in folder in java

Tags: java

```
 byte[] in = decrypt(ut.readBytesFromFile(fin));

Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\AIMP3\\AIMP3.exe","C:\\Users\\ACER\\Desktop\\Shox.mp3"}); 
File fmp3 = new File("C:\\Users\\ACER\\Desktop\\Shox.mp3");
ut.writeBytesToFile(fmp3, in);
```

For the second argument of `exec()` I need to give my byte array instead of a file directory. How can I do this?

Comment: "...convert it to a file without saving it anywhere..." makes no sense. A file is an entry in a file system and its associated data. A file system qualifies as somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

**If** AIMP3.exe is willing to read from stdin ("standard in") rather than from a named file, you can do this by writing to the output stream you can get from `Process`'s [`getOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getOutputStream--). Data written to that stream is piped to the process's stdin.

But again, it requires that AIMP3.exe have a means of reading from stdin rather than a named file, which is more common in *nix utilities than in Windows ones (though certainly not unheard of in Windows utilities).